# Walked on new grout too soon

Tags: grout

So a certain someone (my husband) “accidentally” walked on our newly grouted porcelain tile floor about 3 hours after it had been finished. While nothing looks disturbed, are we destined to have cracks emerge sooner rather than later?It was TEC grout, although I’m not sure which type.

Thanks for your help![image]

Comment: What's the width of the grout lines?

Comment: I’m not sure exactly. The tiles are in a herringbone pattern. Is more narrow better in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tile had already fully set for at least 24 hours before grouting I expect. So walking on it would be safe. The only damage that walking on uncured grout would cause is deforming the grout itself. If you see no evidence of smushed grout either your husband did not step on the actual grout or the grout had hardened enough to not be deformed by his steps. In any case I would not expect any trouble with the grout if it looks fine now.